# Template is missing (application cannot find a .js.erb file)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use a create.js.erb templete, located in /app/views/users/
but I get the following error:

```
Template is missing
Missing template users/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/home/tim/fairym/app/views"
```

My controller action, I base it on the following railscast:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload

```
  def create   
    @user = User.create(params[:user])
  end
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it cannot find your template is because, if you notice on the railscast episode, he is doing an AJAX request for a datatype of `script`

```
$('#new_painting').fileupload
    dataType: "script"
```

So depending on how you are doing your link to the create action that link probably expects a html format to be rendered.

```
Template is missing
Missing template users/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], **:formats=>[:html]**, :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/home/tim/fairym/app/views"
```

You can fix this by adding a `render js` to your action or if you are doing an ajax request make sure your datatype is set to script.

Comment: I did do a request for 'script' in my js.coffee file, but for some reason the server picked it up. It worked only after I've added a respond_to. This is quite strange.

Answer (score 3):

It's not expecting a js file. Add a `respond_to` block to your method:

```
def create
  @user = User.create(params[:user])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    # add more 'format' calls for any other formats this method should ever respond to.
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is already answered, but I had the same problem and error message, and solved it by adding "remote: true" to my form.  You'll need this whenever submitting an ajax call on a form.

I know this is obvious to most, but not to newbies like myself who commonly forget these things.

For example:

```
<%= form_for([@club, @club_order], remote: true) do |f|  %>
```

Hope this helps.